# Internal server error when adding products to Order

Tags: gack, orderitem

**Given:**

- User w/ Profile cloned from `Minimum Access - Salesforce` plus permission sets

**When:**

- User creates an Order
- User adds Products to Order

  - selects Product(s) and clicks NEXT
  - expecting to see the Edit Selected Products screen, but ...

**RESULT**

Lightning: `Unfortunately there was a problem. Please try again`; followed
by `Can't load the list view`

Classic: `Internal Server Error, Error ID: 552389126-100398 (431979318)`

It works fine for System Admin users so clearly the issue is with permissions, but which one(s)?

Answer (score 1):

*I'll admit shamelessly, that for GACKs, given that we have Premier Support, I'm not shy about offloading problem solving to SFDC, so they get credit for the answer.*

Root cause:

- Users with Profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce` or clones thereof, won't ordinarily be assigned page layouts.
- The `Edit Selected Products` screen is controlled by the `Order Product Multi-Line Layout` for a given Order Product page layout.
- So, given that the running user did not have any Order Product page layout assigned to their *clone-of-minimum-access-salesforce* Profile, SFDC decides in Classic to throw a GACK and in Lightning, a friendlified GACK.

SFDC PM has no intention of making page layout assignments by Permission Set at least as of this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdlSPUAZ/permission-sets-with-page-layout-assignment), preferring to use dynamic forms; but for the Add Order Product sequence, dynamic forms are not helpful.